# Turn off auto subscription to notifications on BitBucket

Tags: notifications, bitbucket, subscription

Every time I approve any pull request on our company's BitBucket server it automatically subscribes me to a notification to that pull request and then send me e-mails about what was done. It is completely annoying. Is there a way to turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

If you check this [post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-disable-automatic-watches-for-commits-on-which-I-comment/qaq-p/639289) you can see that there is no way to disable it. It is a bad experience for me too.

Answer (score -1):

In e-mail you should press this link on bottom: "unsubscribe commit emails from this repository"

Comment: There is nothing like that :(
Only "You can unwatch this pull request to stop receiving email updates. Don't want to receive batch emails anymore? Update your notification settings. "